# Black Ops 2 freezes when attempting to play Zombies multiplayer

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When I try to play zombies multiplayer, it freezes on a black screen when the match starts. I've been looking online for hours for an answer but no luck.

Comment: Its possible that your disc is damaged. This happened to my Black Ops 1 disc, it would always freeze when loading certain maps. If so, try taking it somewhere to get the disc cleaned.

Comment: there really isn't anything we can do about this unless you provide more info

Comment: Reset your system cache(go to system settings, storage, yellow button, clear system cache.)

Comment: Do you have DLC? If you do, redownload it before starting your game.

Comment: Online or offline?

Comment: Are you hosting or joining?

Answer (score 1):

try cleaning the disk with a wipe or paper towel etc. (dont add water) and try it. Also maby it's your blueray lens you chould buy cleaners online.

if your playing online try checking your Internet connection. but as David toh said try giving some more info. ex: are you playing online, how often does it freeze, and if the game is new or used. (which often times helps a lot)

hope this helps good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your disk if it has scratches get a cd buffer if not it might be disconection from internet, dirty cd or you might need to warm up your xbox just leave it on home for about ten minutes the try